# Getting service rate based on time/day of service

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, csv, interval

I have a long roster where I'd like to categorize the rates by time/day of service. Most shifts ends the same date but there are some special cases where the shift ends on a different date. I have to prorate those shifts. My solutions seems to have used a lot of for loops. I would appreciate any help improving my coding.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time
from scrape import scrape
import csv

def time_intersect(start_A, end_A, start_B, end_B):
    """
    accepts 2 timeframe and return the overlap
    :param start_A: datetime
    :param end_A: datetime
    :param start_B: datetime
    :param end_B: datetime
    :return: timedelta
    """
    latest_start = max(start_A, start_B)
    earliest_end = min(end_A, end_B)
    if latest_start <= earliest_end:
        return (earliest_end - latest_start).total_seconds()/3600
    else:
        return 0

def create_datelist(start_A, end_B, time_start, time_end, sat=False, sun=False):
    """
    takes 2 datetime object iterates to all dates in range of the 2 datetime object
    and combine the time_start and time_end to all dates in range. Returns a list of 2 datetime item list

    :param start_A: datetime
    :param end_B: datetime
    :param time_start: int 0 to 23
    :param time_end: int 0 to 23
    :return: datetime
    """
    if time_start > time_end:
        day_offset = 1
    else:
        day_offset = 0
    counter = 0
    datelist = []
    while True:
        if sat and start_A.weekday() == 5:
            datelist.append([datetime.combine(start_A, time(0)),
                             datetime.combine(start_A + timedelta(days=1), time(0))])
        elif sun and start_A.weekday() == 6:
            datelist.append([datetime.combine(start_A, time(0)),
                             datetime.combine(start_A + timedelta(days=1), time(0))])
        elif not sat and not sun:
            datelist.append([datetime.combine(start_A, time(time_start)),
                             datetime.combine(start_A + timedelta(days=day_offset), time(time_end))])

        counter += 1
        start_A += timedelta(days=counter)
        if start_A.date() > end_B.date():
            break
    return datelist

#Sample data from scrape() [[2019-03-19 00:00:00,2019-03-19 06:00:00,Staff name,Client name]] there would 1000+ items
rosters = scrape()
rates = {'am':48.14,
         'pm':52.79,
         'on':34.14,
         'sat':66.77,
         'sun':85.45}
roster_rated = []
for roster in rosters:
    mornings = create_datelist(roster[0],roster[1],6,20)
    evenings = create_datelist(roster[0],roster[1],20,0)
    over_nights = create_datelist(roster[0],roster[1],0,6)

    if roster[1].hour == 0:#adjust for midnight
        roster[1] += timedelta(days=1)
    sat = 0
    sun = 0
    am = 0
    pm = 0
    on = 0
    if roster[0].weekday() == 5:
        saturdays = create_datelist(roster[0], roster[1], 0, 6, sat=True)
        for saturday in saturdays:
            sat += time_intersect(roster[0], roster[1], saturday[0], saturday[1])
    elif roster[0].weekday() == 6:
        sundays = create_datelist(roster[0], roster[1], 0, 6, sun=True)
        for sunday in sundays:
            sun += time_intersect(roster[0], roster[1], sunday[0], sunday[1])
    else:
        for morning in mornings:
            am += time_intersect(roster[0], roster[1], morning[0], morning[1])
        for evening in evenings:
            pm += time_intersect(roster[0], roster[1], evening[0], evening[1])
        for over_night in over_nights:
            on += time_intersect(roster[0], roster[1], over_night[0], over_night[1])


    roster.extend([am,am*rates['am'],pm,pm*rates['pm'],on,on*rates['on'],sat,sat*rates['sat'],sun,sun*rates['sun']])
    roster_rated.append(roster)

with open('roster_rated.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for each in roster_rated:
        writer.writerow(each)
```

Sample Input

```
from,to,staff,client
8/04/2019 8:30,8/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
8/04/2019 12:00,8/04/2019 15:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
8/04/2019 20:00,8/04/2019 21:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
8/04/2019 10:00,8/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
9/04/2019 8:30,9/04/2019 11:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
9/04/2019 13:30,9/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
9/04/2019 20:00,9/04/2019 21:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
9/04/2019 22:00,9/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
10/04/2019 9:00,10/04/2019 12:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
10/04/2019 13:30,10/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
10/04/2019 13:30,10/04/2019 14:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
10/04/2019 22:00,10/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
11/04/2019 8:30,11/04/2019 11:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
11/04/2019 11:00,11/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
11/04/2019 8:00,11/04/2019 21:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
11/04/2019 22:00,11/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
12/04/2019 8:30,12/04/2019 11:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
12/04/2019 11:30,12/04/2019 16:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
12/04/2019 22:00,12/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
13/04/2019 8:30,13/04/2019 10:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
13/04/2019 13:30,13/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
13/04/2019 16:00,13/04/2019 17:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
13/04/2019 20:00,13/04/2019 21:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
13/04/2019 22:00,13/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
14/04/2019 8:30,14/04/2019 10:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
14/04/2019 13:30,14/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
14/04/2019 16:00,14/04/2019 17:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
14/04/2019 22:00,14/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz
```

Expected Outcome

```
from,to,staff,client,am,am_cost,pm,pm_cost,on,on_cost,sat,sat_cost,sun,sun_cost
8/04/2019 8:30,8/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,2.5,120.35,12,633.48,0,0,0,0,0,0
8/04/2019 12:00,8/04/2019 15:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,3,144.42,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
8/04/2019 20:00,8/04/2019 21:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,1.5,79.185,0,0,0,0,0,0
8/04/2019 10:00,8/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,12,577.68,1,52.79,0,0,0,0,0,0
9/04/2019 8:30,9/04/2019 11:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,2.5,120.35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
9/04/2019 13:30,9/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,1,48.14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
9/04/2019 20:00,9/04/2019 21:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,1.5,79.185,0,0,0,0,0,0
9/04/2019 22:00,9/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,1,52.79,0,0,0,0,0,0
10/04/2019 9:00,10/04/2019 12:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,3,144.42,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
10/04/2019 13:30,10/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,1,48.14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
10/04/2019 13:30,10/04/2019 14:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0.5,24.07,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
10/04/2019 22:00,10/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,1,52.79,0,0,0,0,0,0
11/04/2019 8:30,11/04/2019 11:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,2.5,120.35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
11/04/2019 11:00,11/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,3.5,168.49,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
11/04/2019 8:00,11/04/2019 21:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,12,577.68,1.5,79.185,0,0,0,0,0,0
11/04/2019 22:00,11/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,1,52.79,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/04/2019 8:30,12/04/2019 11:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,2.5,120.35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/04/2019 11:30,12/04/2019 16:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,5,240.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/04/2019 22:00,12/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,1,52.79,0,0,0,0,0,0
13/04/2019 8:30,13/04/2019 10:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,133.54,0,0
13/04/2019 13:30,13/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,66.77,0,0
13/04/2019 16:00,13/04/2019 17:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,66.77,0,0
13/04/2019 20:00,13/04/2019 21:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.5,100.155,0,0
13/04/2019 22:00,13/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,66.77,0,0
14/04/2019 8:30,14/04/2019 10:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,170.9
14/04/2019 13:30,14/04/2019 14:30,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,85.45
14/04/2019 16:00,14/04/2019 17:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,85.45
14/04/2019 22:00,14/04/2019 23:00,John Doe,Juan Dela Cruz,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,85.45
```